# How to unlock a excel VBA project? the known methods are not working

Tags: excel, vba

we have an excel file that we were working but unfortunately, the guy who was working has left. we have no way to find the VBA password.

I have tried all the methods that are there on the web that talks about changing the DBP text with hex, but none have worked.

if any great soul wants to have a look at the file, here it is.
https://mega.nz/file/TMwDXZKR#pUQF3HeRm3JIbu1kvOUO6bsU8ConD50A8Tk6F_ny0vY

Comment: The name of the file is `excel_vba.xlsm`. Nothing is locked. The data is just gone. All the hidden worksheets that the code in `Module2` is referring to are gone. `Module1` is empty. And its complaining about an `MT4.exe` file that it cannot find. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks for looking into the file. Have a look, the file has two VBA projects. One is locked and the other one is open. The main part of the work is done in the locked VBAproject. Yes, the worksheet is getting dynamic data via a DDE link from another program. Hope this helps to trouble shoot. Thanks

Comment: In otherwords that's what we think. Not sure or I have no idea how the DDE link works

Comment: You are right VBasic2008. Yes, we didn't realize that it was an excel file without any macros. DDE link is direct and everything else was built around that. Thanks for opening the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at, it provides several methods depending what has been locked actually
https://exceloffthegrid.com/removing-cracking-excel-passwords-with-vba/

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at these links before and have tried to use those methods as well. Unfortunately, didnt work on this sheet. As I commented, this file has two VBA projects and one is locked and other one is not. The sheet is using DDE to get data from another application.